# Is there any complication in sharepoint and leap year

Tags: 2007

Are there any complications with SharePoint and leap years. We have a 2007 installation and we just wan to make sure no issues will arise.

Is there any documentation about it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any links to documentation that says SharePoint 2007 supports leap years. But, considering how popular SharePoint is, if there was a problem it would most certainly show up in a Google Search for 'SharePoint leap year'.